# How can I calculate business/SLA hours with iterating over each second?

Tags: perl

Before I spend a lot of time writing the only solution I can think of I was wondering if I'm doing it an inefficient way.

Once a support ticket is closed, a script is triggered, the script is passed an array of 'status-change-events' that happened from call open to close. So you might have 5 changes: new, open, active, stalled, resolved. Each one of these events has a timestamp associated with it.

What I need to do is calculate how much time the call was with us (new, open, active) and how much time it was with the customer (stalled). I also need to figure out how much of the 'us' time was within core hours 08:00 - 18:00 (and how many were non-core), and weekends/bank holidays count towards non-core hours.

My current idea is to for each status change, iterate over every second that occurred and check for core/non_core, and log it.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
time_since_last = ticket->creation_date

foreach events as event {
    time_now = time_since_last

    while (time_now < ticket->event_date) {

        if ticket->status = stalled {

            customer_fault_stalled++

        } else {

            work out if it was our fault or not
            add to the appropriate counter etc

        }

        time_now++
    }
}
```

Apologies if it's a little unclear, it's a fairly longwinded problem. Also I'm aware this may be slightly off of SO question guidelines, but I can't think of a better way of wording it and I need some advice before I spend days writing it this way.

Comment: If you show some sample data you will be more likely to get an accurate solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the right idea, but recalculating the status of every ticket for every second of elapsed time will take a lot processing, and nothing will have changed for the vast majority of those one-second intervals

The way event simulations work, and the way I think you should write your application, is to create a list of all events where the status might change. So you will want to include all of the *status change events* for every ticket as well as the start and end of core time on all non-bank-holiday weekdays

That list of events is sorted by timestamp, after which you can just process each event as if your per-second counter has reached that time. The difference is that you no longer have to count through the many intervening seconds where nothing changes, and you should end up with a much more efficient application

I hope that's clear. You may find it easier to process each ticket separately, but the maximum gain will be achieved by processing all tickets simultaneously. You will still have a sorted sequence of events to process, but you will avoid having to reprocess the same core time start and end events over and over again

One more thing I noticed is that you can probably ignore any `open` status change events. I would guess that tickets either go from `new` to `open` and then `active`, or straight from `new` to `resolved`. So a switch between *with your company* and *with the customer* will never be made at an `open` event, and so they can be ignored. Please check this as I am only speaking from my intuition, and clearly know nothing about how your ticketing system has been designed

Comment: Hi, thanks, you've helped me out. The only issue I'm facing, is let's say ticket is new at 07:00 and then resolved at 10:00 - that means 3h or 180 mins to resolve. It's easy to work out $duration=$end-$start, but how do I then work out, without iteration, that since our business hours are 08:00 onwards, that we have a non-core value of 60 mins, and a core value of 120 mins? 

This also must span days, so if a ticket was new 7am Monday, resolved 10am Wednesday, it's easy to work out durations etc but then working out core vs non-core hours is what lead me to thinking of just iterating secs/mins

Comment: That's why I suggest mixing the changes between core and non-core time in with the sorted status change events. At these points every ticket that has had an `open` event but not a `close` event should have its time in the current state incremented by the duration of the preceding interval. Its *identical* to what you would do at one-second intervals except that the intervals vary in length and cover periods where nothing at all changes. If you have some test data then I can write an example program

Comment: I've re-read what you wrote a couple of times. Due to the system in use, I have to loop in a fashion similar to 'foreach transactions as transaction', but there's nothing saying I couldn't then simply stick these transactions in to a list/array, and then act upon them. Am I getting the wrong idea, or are you saying I should have my list of events (known as transactions) and then inject additional transactions for changes between core/non-core hours?

Comment: @DanWalker: Don't work from the database. Pull out an array of all the transactions you're interested in, add the core/non-core switch events, sort everything by time, and process it. What sublanguage is `foreach transactions as transaction`?

Comment: Well you say 'interested in' but I'll need to pull a list of all transactions to figure out what I'm interested in. The language is Perl.

Comment: @DanWalker: You really don't explain enough about your application for me to help any further. If you're still having trouble then you should open a new question and show your Perl code. And `foreach transactions as transaction` isn't Perl so I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

I would not iterate over the seconds. Depending on the cost of your calculations that could be quite costly. It would be better to calculate the borders between core/outside core.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $customer_time;
my $our_time_outside;
my $our_time_core;

foreach my $event ($ticket->events) {
    my $current_ts = $event->start_ts;
    while ($current_ts < $event->end_ts) {
        if ($event->status eq 'stalled') {
            $customer_time += $event->end_ts - $current_ts;
            $current_ts = $event->end_ts;
        }
        elsif (is_core_hours($current_ts)) {
            my $next_ts = min(end_of_core_hours($current_ts), $event->end_ts);
            $our_time_core += $next_ts - $current_ts;
            $current_ts = $next_ts;
        }
        else {
            my $next_ts = min(start_of_core_hours($current_ts), $event->end_ts);
            $our_time_outside += $next_ts - $current_ts;
            $current_ts = $next_ts;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you'd want to iterate over every second. That seems very wasteful.

- Get a list of all of the events for a given ticket.
- Add to the list any boundaries between core and non-core times.
- Sort this list into chronological order.
- For each consecutive pair of events in the list, subtract the later from the earlier to get a duration.
- Add that duration to the appropriate bucket.

And the usual caveats for dealing with dates and times apply here:

- Use a library (I recommend [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) together with [DateTime::Duration](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Duration))
- Convert all of your timestamps to UTC as soon as you get them. Only convert back to local time just before displaying them to the user.